# dll is not updating in production server

Tags: c++, asp.net

I have a Visual Studio project developed in asp.net that calls a .dll developed in C++. I modified the .dll file and replaced the old file located in the bin folder. Locally, the website worked fine. I did the same in the production server, but the change was ignored, the web site behaved like the previous file. Why?

I did a test leaving the message “new version” in .cs file to check if it is updated in the production server. And it is indeed.

I did another test cleaning the history browser, but the problem remained. 
In another test, I removed the dll file from the bin folder, and the website continued to work normally. How is that possible?

I read from a forum ([link](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/1021521/How-to-update-dlls-of-an-existing-application-in-I)) that asp.net makes a "shadow copy" of the files and loads them from the copy. But it should not be a problem.

Comment: Did you restart the sever to it had a chance to reaload that library?

Comment: The server is in a website host, it is out of my reach to do that. But it updated the .cs files. I do not know why it did not happen with the .dll file.

Comment: @VTT, a website hosted in IIS does not need a server restart to load the new libraries. Any changes made to the BIN folder will trigger an AppPool recycle and will reload the entire website.

Comment: It depends on your webhost - _restarting_ the _application_ (not necessarily the _server_) should hopefully resolve your issue. Check your host for that function, otherwise, you can "manually" do so, by resetting your `web.config` (which triggers an app restart) - no changes, just overwrite it. Some webhosts require that you delete and then upload to reset whatever cache they are employing (instead of just overwriting). Hth.

Comment: I tested now and it worked. I have not changed anything, so I am not sure the reason. Is it possible to exist a delay between the replacement of the file and the propagation to the website?

Comment: Can't speak for _all_ webhosts, but I had similar experience with hosts that employ file caching systems. So yes, there can be a "delay" unless you explicitly perform steps to do a "reset" of the cached resources. In my case, as above, not just overwrite, but explicitly _delete_ the file _then replace it_ - this ensures that the cache is reset and new file/s are used. Hth